# How do I "source" something in my .vimrc file?

Tags: plugins, vi, vim

I've been working on expanding my vim-foo lately and I've run across a couple of plugins ([autotag.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1343) for example) that require them to be "sourced" in my .vimrc file. What exactly does this mean and how do I do it?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Sourcing a file is 'executing' it. Essentially, each line of the file is considered a command. Sourcing it is the same as typing each command in order. You source with the command `:source` (usually shortened to `:so`).

So if you source `myStuff.vim`

```
:so myStuff.vim
```

and if `myStuff.vim` contained these lines

```
set xx iI just intersted this<C-]>
set yy bbbb4dw
```

It's the same as if you typed those commands into Vim

```
:set xx iI just intersted this<C-]>
:set yy bbbb4dw
```

The only file sourced by default is the `.vimrc`(`_vimrc` on windows) so that's a place you can keep all the commands you use to set up Vim every time.

Where it gets interesting is the fact that since a sourced file is just a series of commands, and sourcing is a command, you can source files from your source files. So plugins you use every time could be sourced when you start up Vim by adding a line to your `.vimrc` like this

```
 so myPlugin.vim
```

Comment: What does `so!` do?  I ran it because I thought it'd forcibly resource my `.vimrc` and it started walking through the file I was editing (my `.vimrc`) and was indenting crap in weird ways and all kinds of weird stuff was happening.

Comment: It executes the files in "normal" mode (i.e., what would happen if you didn't add the ":" in front).

Answer (score 47):

Files in your .vim/plugin directory are sourced (loaded) automatically.

Comment: Also, their file name must end by *.vim*

Comment: yeah but only once per startup, right? is it when you launch terminal/powershell, or when you use the vim command to edit some file?

Comment: @3pitt AFAIK, it's every time the vim command is run.

Answer (score 12):

There is always the [:source file](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:source) command. I usually write `.vimrc` that contains custom commands and what not for the console application and then a `.gvimrc` that contains additional goodies that are appropriate for a windowed version.  My `.gvimrc` starts with `source $HOME/.vimrc` to pick up everything from the console version before adding in new stuff.

Comment: My versions of vim, at least, all source .vimrc all the time. Are you sure you need to source .vimrc?

Comment: @DavClark: it looks like you might be right about that.  I've been doing this for a long time and never thought twice about it.  The help file definitely states that this is not necessary... hmmm.

Answer (score 7):

There are normally two vimrc files, one is _vimrc and the other _gvimrc (in the first one are the things for vim, and in the second for gvim - graphical things) - although most people I know just put everything in _vimrc.

A good practice is to keep all your extra files (plugins, colorschemes, snippets ...) in a separate (your own) vimfiles directory (which you can take with you).

If you do

```
:help vimfiles
```

vim will tell your vimfiles directory should be located. It depends somewhat on the platform (win, unix). On windows the usual is in your user folder (documents and settings, then user ...).
In vimfiles directory there are a couple of subdirectories. Amongst them is the "plugin" subdirectory. Plugins put in that dir will be loaded automatically (also plugins put in subdirectories of "plugin").
If you do not wish to load it automatically, just put it in your "vimfiles", or some other directory, and

```
:so plugin_name.vim (with the appropriate path)
(you can use the $vim, $vimfiles, and $home as shortcuts when defining path to plugin)
```